# How do I tell if two addresses are in the same page file?

Tags: memory, memory-management, paging, pagefile

What math is involved and how do I tell if two addresses are in the same 4 kilobyte page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, assuming 4 KiB pages,

```
#include <stdint.h>
bool same_page(const void *x, const void *y)
{
    uintptr_t mask = ~(uintptr_t) 4095;
    return ((uintptr_t) x & mask) == ((uintptr_t) y & mask);
}
```

This will get ugly quickly since pages have a variable size on common architectures, and the page size of a particular region of memory can and will be changed by the operating system on the fly depending on application memory usage patters.

(Note that memory pages are *virtual memory* and not *physical memory.*  Strictly speaking, it does not make sense to talk about physical pages, although we usually understand when someone says "physical page" they mean "physical memory corresponding to a page".)